# Metadata for assigned Home Page Layouts

Tags: deployment, profile, metadata, home-page-layout

I've just created a customised Home Page Layout and assigned it to a couple of profiles. I now want that assignment to be deployable to other sandboxes via metadata. Is this possible?

Or does this have to be done manually?

Comment: did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have the same question. Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. Sorry.